# Why does one conversion of an array element to an integer work and the other now work?

Tags: objective-c, nsarray

When I convert an array element to an integer using this statement

```
int test=(int)[myArray objectAtIndex:2];
```

later use of "test" passed to other commands fails.However, this statement works

```
int test=[[myArray objectAtIndex2]intValue];
```

What is the difference between these two types of conversion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first is a cast. You're taking the object and casting it to an int, which will give you an int that contains the address of the object (and under 64-bit it will only contain the low 32 bits of the address). This isn't at all what you want.

The second is a method call for `-intValue`, which is implemented by `NSNumber` (and `NSString`) to return the `int` that the `NSNumber` (or `NSString`) object represents. This is (presumably) what you actually want.

Answer (score 0):

The first statement is not a conversion. It is a cast of the pointer stored as element 2 in your array. The statement just assigns value of that pointer (casted to an `int`) to the variable.

The second statement is a converstion. It calls `-intValue` on object that pointer stored at that index 2 points to (possibly a `NSNumber` instance).

Answer (score 0):

`- intValue` works on objects of type `NSString *` and `NSNumber *`.

If your object is actually `@"123"`, or an `[NSNumber numberWithInt:123]` instead of just `int 123`, then using `- intValue` will convert it to `123`. If you try and cast it directly using `(int)` and it's one of the above two types, then you'll run into errors accessing it as an `int` (because it's not, it's a more complex type).